# Form validation with flask without wtforms

Tags: python, validation, flask

I have problem with form validation in Flask. In login.html I have:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<center>Sign In</center>

<form action="/login" method="post" >
<div class="login">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username">  
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">  
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
</div>

<div class="shadow"></div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

In routes.py I have:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    if request.method == 'POST'and form.validate():
        if(request.form["username"] is None or request.form["password"] is None):
            flash("fill inputs")

    else:
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=request.form["username"]).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(request.form["password"]):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user)

        userCookie = request.form['username']
        resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
        resp.set_cookie('user', userCookie)

        next_page = request.args.get('next')
            if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
                next_page = url_for('index')
                return resp
            return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In')
```

Unfortunately, after clicking to log in, nothing happens even if I write correct username and password. Before I was using WTForms and everything worked well, but I couldnt add css to modify form and after changing it, the validation dosnt work well. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: 1. Can you be more specific about what isn't working?  2.  You can still use wtforms to validate the POST data, even if you are not using wtforms to render the form in the template (but you will have to ensure that input names, types etc match).

Comment: ATM, even if I write correct data to login, Im not redirected to main page and the cookies arent set.It looks like after POST request, script cant connect my form with code.

Comment: And I will try again to use wtforms and change layout of my form

Answer (score 0):

Add a `value="{{request.form[<name>]}}"` in your `<input>` tags.

```html
<input type="username" name="username" placeholder="johndoe" value="{{ request.form['username'] }}">
<!-- Update the other input tags -->
```

Your current `<input>` tags do not extract data from the form fields